# iOS Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'UIColor*' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: ios, uipickerview, textcolor

I have a pickerview that is getting its information from a separate AFPickerView file. I'm getting the error "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'UIColor*' is disallowed with ARC". Any suggestions on an easy fix for this?

Here is the code that it effects:

```
[visibleViews minusSet:recycledViews];

    // add missing pages
    for (int index = firstNeededViewIndex; index <= lastNeededViewIndex; index++) 
    {
        if (![self isDisplayingViewForIndex:index]) 
        {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self dequeueRecycledView];

            if (label == nil)
            {
                label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_rowIndent, 0, self.frame.size.width - _rowIndent, 39.0)];
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label.font = self.rowFont;
                label.textColor = RGBACOLOR(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75);
            }

            [self configureView:label atIndex:index];
            [contentView addSubview:label];
            [visibleViews addObject:label];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
    #import "AFPickerView.h"

@implementation AFPickerView

#pragma mark - Synthesization

@synthesize dataSource;
@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize selectedRow = currentRow;
@synthesize rowFont = _rowFont;
@synthesize rowIndent = _rowIndent;




#pragma mark - Custom getters/setters

- (void)setSelectedRow:(int)selectedRow
{
    if (selectedRow >= rowsCount)
        return;

    currentRow = selectedRow;
    [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 39.0 * currentRow) animated:NO];
}




- (void)setRowFont:(UIFont *)rowFont
{
    _rowFont = rowFont;

    for (UILabel *aLabel in visibleViews) 
    {
        aLabel.font = _rowFont;
    }

    for (UILabel *aLabel in recycledViews) 
    {
        aLabel.font = _rowFont;
    }
}




- (void)setRowIndent:(CGFloat)rowIndent
{
    _rowIndent = rowIndent;

    for (UILabel *aLabel in visibleViews) 
    {
        CGRect frame = aLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x = _rowIndent;
        frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - _rowIndent;
        aLabel.frame = frame;
    }

    for (UILabel *aLabel in recycledViews) 
    {
        CGRect frame = aLabel.frame;
        frame.origin.x = _rowIndent;
        frame.size.width = self.frame.size.width - _rowIndent;
        aLabel.frame = frame;
    }
}




#pragma mark - Initialization

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // setup
        [self setup];

        // backgound
        UIImageView *bacground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerBackground.png"]];
        [self addSubview:bacground];

        // content
        contentView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
        contentView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        contentView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        contentView.delegate = self;
        [self addSubview:contentView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didTap:)];
        [contentView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


        // shadows
        UIImageView *shadows = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerShadows.png"]];
        [self addSubview:shadows];

        // glass
        UIImage *glassImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pickerGlass.png"];
        glassImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 76.0, glassImage.size.width, glassImage.size.height)];
        glassImageView.image = glassImage;
        [self addSubview:glassImageView];
    }
    return self;
}




- (void)setup
{
    _rowFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];
    _rowIndent = 30.0;

    currentRow = 0;
    rowsCount = 0;
    visibleViews = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    recycledViews = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
}




#pragma mark - Buisness

- (void)reloadData
{
    // empry views
    currentRow = 0;
    rowsCount = 0;

    for (UIView *aView in visibleViews) 
        [aView removeFromSuperview];

    for (UIView *aView in recycledViews)
        [aView removeFromSuperview];

    visibleViews = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    recycledViews = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    rowsCount = [dataSource numberOfRowsInPickerView:self];
    [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:NO];
    contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentView.frame.size.width, 39.0 * rowsCount + 4 * 39.0);    
    [self tileViews];
}




- (void)determineCurrentRow
{
    CGFloat delta = contentView.contentOffset.y;
    int position = round(delta / 39.0);
    currentRow = position;
    [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 39.0 * position) animated:YES];
    [delegate pickerView:self didSelectRow:currentRow];
}




- (void)didTap:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint point = [tapRecognizer locationInView:self];
    int steps = floor(point.y / 39) - 2;
    [self makeSteps:steps];
}




- (void)makeSteps:(int)steps
{
    if (steps == 0 || steps > 2 || steps < -2)
        return;

    [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 39.0 * currentRow) animated:NO];

    int newRow = currentRow + steps;
    if (newRow < 0 || newRow >= rowsCount)
    {
        if (steps == -2)
            [self makeSteps:-1];
        else if (steps == 2)
            [self makeSteps:1];

        return;
    }

    currentRow = currentRow + steps;
    [contentView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 39.0 * currentRow) animated:YES];
    [delegate pickerView:self didSelectRow:currentRow];
}




#pragma mark - recycle queue

- (UIView *)dequeueRecycledView
{
    UIView *aView = [recycledViews anyObject];

    if (aView) 
        [recycledViews removeObject:aView];
    return aView;
}



- (BOOL)isDisplayingViewForIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    BOOL foundPage = NO;
    for (UIView *aView in visibleViews) 
    {
        int viewIndex = aView.frame.origin.y / 39.0 - 2;
        if (viewIndex == index) 
        {
            foundPage = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundPage;
}




- (void)tileViews
{
    // Calculate which pages are visible
    CGRect visibleBounds = contentView.bounds;
    int firstNeededViewIndex = floorf(CGRectGetMinY(visibleBounds) / 39.0) - 2;
    int lastNeededViewIndex  = floorf((CGRectGetMaxY(visibleBounds) / 39.0)) - 2;
    firstNeededViewIndex = MAX(firstNeededViewIndex, 0);
    lastNeededViewIndex  = MIN(lastNeededViewIndex, rowsCount - 1);

    // Recycle no-longer-visible pages 
    for (UIView *aView in visibleViews) 
    {
        int viewIndex = aView.frame.origin.y / 39 - 2;
        if (viewIndex < firstNeededViewIndex || viewIndex > lastNeededViewIndex) 
        {
            [recycledViews addObject:aView];
            [aView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    [visibleViews minusSet:recycledViews];

    // add missing pages
    for (int index = firstNeededViewIndex; index <= lastNeededViewIndex; index++) 
    {
        if (![self isDisplayingViewForIndex:index]) 
        {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self dequeueRecycledView];

            if (label == nil)
            {
                label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_rowIndent, 0, self.frame.size.width - _rowIndent, 39.0)];
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label.font = self.rowFont;
                label.textColor = RGBACOLOR(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75);
            }

            [self configureView:label atIndex:index];
            [contentView addSubview:label];
            [visibleViews addObject:label];
        }
    }
}




- (void)configureView:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
    label.text = [dataSource pickerView:self titleForRow:index];
    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 39.0 * index + 78.0;
    label.frame = frame;
}




#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self tileViews];
}




- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
        [self determineCurrentRow];
}




- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self determineCurrentRow];
}

@end
```

Comment: Probably the issue with `label.textColor = RGBACOLOR(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75);` Can you please add the macro definition to your question ?

Comment: Also it's helpful to tell us the line that this is occurring on

Comment: Just an idea: have you tried `label.textColor = [UIColor RGBACOLOR(...)];`?

Comment: Sorry it is label.textColor = RGBAColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.75); that is showing the error on. I will update with the full code.

Comment: @AustinMullins just tried but with no joy.

Comment: No need for the full code. It makes the issue harder to find.

Comment: @PaulH Yeah it's probably your macro for RGBACOLOR. This should work with ARC label.textColor = `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.75f]`

Comment: @PaulH Added it as an answer, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work with ARC. Replace RGBACOLOR with `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha`

```
label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.75f];
```